# How do you create two grid columns like the Entry Edit page within a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, user-interface

I have a plugin where I'd like my CP tab to output two columns just like the entry page.  On the left, would be the body and then there would be a nice dividing gap and then on the right there would be a aside column.

I've tried to copy the way that the Entry Edit page works but I must be missing something.

Extending `_layouts/cp` wraps everything on the page with the following three divs which don't seem to get output at all on the Entry Edit page:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="pane">
             ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How does the entry page get rid of these divs?  I'm not seeing anything obvious in the templates.

**EDIT** To be clear, I can create the layout that I want, except for the fact that the layout I want gets wrapped in the above code and makes the gutter disappear and messes up the padding around the two columns on the page.  If I extend the {% extends '_layouts/cp' %} and remove those three divs above, just like the Edit and Entry page seems to do somehow, the page displays just as I want it to.

What I can't figure out is how the Entry page is getting rid of those three divs. It uses {% extends '_layouts/cp' %} and those divs do not appear on the Edit an Entry page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templates/layouts/_cp.html` has

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="pane">
```

nested inside the `{% block main %}` (line  207) and `templates/entries/_edit.html` is overriding that `block main`, so those grid,item,pane divs get overridden too.

Comment: Bingo! Looked right past that. Using {% block main %} works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ben if you are using `{% extends '_layouts/cp' %}` how about something like this?

```
{% set sidebar %}
     <div class="buttons">
           <a href="{{ url('') }}"><div class="btn submit add icon">New Button</div></a>
     </div>
{% endset %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam.  In my tests {% set sidebar %} controlled the column to the left of the layout like on the Entries listing page, where I am hoping to have a column on the right of the layout, like on the Edit an Entry page.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Yes I'd be interested in this too.